# Accessing Properties.Settings.Default from Class?

Tags: c#

When I create a Console App I can right click on the project in Visual Studio 2008 Pro. click Properties > Go To Settings enter a Application Scope Setting and then access it from code like

```
Console.WriteLine(Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting.ToString());
```

When I do the same thing in a Class Project and try to assign the the Applicatin Scope Setting to a variable like

```
this.mySettingVariable = Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting.ToString();
```

I get an the error when building that "The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context."

What am I doing wrong and how can I access the Application Scoped properties for a class project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add settings to the class library project.  You cannot access the settings of the EXE project directly.

Giving a class library project its own settings is possible but it is a hassle.  A DLL cannot have its own .config file, there's only one: the app.exe.config file.  You have to merge the entries in the DLL's app.config file into the app.exe.config file by hand.  Copy and paste with a text editor.  This is not very maintainable.

Another approach is to make these settings properties of the class.  And let the code in the main project initialize them from its own settings.  Or just ditch settings because their a pita and use an .xml file.

Comment: thanks alot. I have been trying to read my .dlls settings and have not been able to call Properties.Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the namespace in the 'usings'.

Also make sure the settings class is public.

Comment: The Settings Access Modifier was set to Internal (which I assume woudl be fine) I changed to Public but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Pulled from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx)

> Because there is no configuration file
>   model for class libraries, application
>   settings do not apply for Class
>   Library projects. The exception is a
>   Visual Studio Tools for Office DLL
>   project, which can have a
>   configuration file.

Comment: But class libraries can still have settings  :)

Comment: Not application scoped...which is what the OP mentioned. I believe user level settings would suffice.

Comment: I use this feature all the time. Believe me it works. You can set all the setting from the main app.config file. Or web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Is your .settings file under the Properties folder in your project?

Comment: Yes I have the "using System.Configuration" at the top of the class

Comment: @TooFat - see my edit regarding location of your settings file.